# What happens when someone apparently gives meaningless or false answers which get voted up?

Tags: discussion, flagging

What happens when someone apparently gives meaningless or false answers which get voted up - especially when it looks like they are seeking extra points?

Is there a way to report such apparent activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think it is sock-puppetry or some other deliberate deception you can flag the answer for moderator's attention.

If it is not deliberate (i.e. it is just some clueless fool fishing for points), you should just downvote and leave a comment pointing out why you think the answer is not helpful.  Then the community will usually sort it out through downvoting.

If there exists another answer that you think is helpful, you should upvote that.

If you have the knowledge, you may try to create a helpful answer yourself.

Comment: If you think it warrants flagging, use a custom reason.  Don't use "not an answer", unless it really isn't an answer.  Moderators aren't the arbiters of whether an answer is right or wrong.

Comment: Sometimes it happens that the questions asked are not clear enough as well, or they are edited along and make some answers appear irrelevant.